90s TV Show, Suave Private-Eye Like Character Possibly Named Connie
This show would have aired in the early 90s, featuring a male suave main character that solved problems (similar to the sub-plots on Burn Notice).  I believe the character had a feminine name (maybe Connie) and drove a convertible Mercedes or Cadillac.  

After scouring the internet for way too long, the show I'm looking for is Pointman.  I had the date a little off (produced in 1995) but I had the character's name right! 
